# How to locate Jquery issues affecting internet explorer

Tags: jquery, html

I've just started trying to learn javascript and jQuery so excuse my simpleness, please!...

I've created a webpage which works perfectly well in most browsers apart from Internet Explorer...  The page loads and displays perfectly well, but seems a little unresponsive compared to Firefox, for example.  The page is rather large as i've not yet properly optimised all images.

When you hover over the links, there is a delay before the :hover state wakes up..

My question...  how would i go about locating the issue?  Is there a tool which shows how the page is loading and what processes are slowing the page?

I have a work in progress test page located here: http://martinwhite.co.uk/greg10

The HTML and CSS are valid so there should be no issues there.  I have done the obvious, by removing various scripts - removing Cufon seemed to help but even without it, the page seemed less responsive than Firefox..

Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated..

Many thanks,  Martin

Answer (score 2):

You can use [firebug plugin](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox to trace most issues with JavaScript, CSS and the DOM

Comment: Thanks Vincent - that was quick!  I didn't realise Firebug could do that... I take it that you referring to the profiler on the console?  I have just run it - but I don't really know how to interpret the results?

Comment: To  really use profiler you will need to use the non-minified versions of the javascript libraries, then you will be able to see which functions are taking the time. since with jquery most functions are anonymous.

Comment: You can simply click the profile button, then load your page or invoke the javascript somehow (maybe move the mouse over the hover point) then click profile again. You see a report showing you what functions were called and how long they took etc.

Comment: There is also a pagespeed addon to this plugin from Google.

Comment: I achieved a grade E with Y-Slow...  I guess that makes me a loser!  I'll follow the advice that it gives and see if that improves things... 

The thing is, is that it's fine in Firefox so i'm unsure how i can find issues that are non affecting to firefox...  It's only IE that displays the issue..  I hate IE, with a passion...

Comment: Hmmm...I think we all get a bit frustrated by the browser incompatibilities that complicate our lives. There is a ie developer toolbar that does give some information in ie. It is not quite as sophisticated as firebug but it may offer some clues. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en